# What's a good f/oss GDI+ (System.Drawing) based graphing and charting component for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gdi+, graph

I want to create basic line, bar, pie and area charts for .NET 3.5 WinForms and I'm interested in finding a free, mature, open-source .NET (preferably C# based) project to help me accomplish that.  I would consider a WPF based project, however I'm more comfortable in GDI+ so I'd rather it used System.Drawing and/or GDI interop as its base technology.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/). 'Nuff said.

Answer (score 0):

This one's quite nice:  [zed graph](http://zedgraph.org)

Comment: Shouldnt these be deleted, since they are duplicates of the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ZedGraph:  http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Shouldnt these be deleted, since they are duplicates of the accepted answer?

Comment: I don't know -- it was just a synchronous timing issue.  We all were answering the question when it had no answers.